# Idiomatic alternative to zero value if you need the zero value

Tags: go

I'm trying to normalize data from a number of sources. One of those sources is JSON with a nullable ID.

```golang
type Entry struct {
  ID *int // Can be null
}
```

What's Go's idiomatic way to deal with a nullable ID, where the number 0 might be a valid ID? I'm torn between what I see as three options.

Do I normalize by passing possibly-nil pointer around?

```golang
type NormalizedEntry struct {
  ID *int
}
```

Do I add a separate HasID property?

```golang
type NormalizedEntry struct {
  HasID bool
  ID    int
}
```

Do I pass -1 instead of 0 to represent the "zero value"? (Like how strings.Index returns -1 if a value is not found)

```golang
type NormalizedEntry struct {
  ID int
}
```

Or is there some other, better, method that I'm not yet aware of?

Comment: I'd vote for the `HasID` but also consider the approach implemented by various `Null*` types of `database/sql`. I mean, you could have your `NullID` type with proper semantics.

Comment: You covered three approaches: pointer, separate field, distinguished value (-1 in your example).  The only other approach that I've seen is the [SQL null types](https://godoc.org/database/sql#NullInt64) mentioned by kostix.  A JSON specific null type can be written with [MarshalJSON](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler.MarshalJSON) and [UnmarshalJSON](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler.UnmarshalJSON) methods to handle the `Valid` field.

Comment: I would vote for the `*int` and it has used in [gorm](http://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) soft delete where some fields don't have `deleted_at` and some of them do.

Comment: I don't think Go has an idiom for that, except maybe the database stuff mentioned above.  However, if you have a large number of these value and they are typically null then I would use a pointer (as long as you're sure the integer don't escape to the heap when it's there).  If you have a lot typically *not* null and you are sure you can never have -ve values then I'd use integer with -1.

Comment: Note that pointers are not friendly to GC and CPU cache locality, so if processing of these chunks of data are on a hot path or you just churn _lots_ of them, using pointers may be suboptimal. Still, it's just and observation; as usually, do not do premature optimizations—measure first.